# select data that have a value from a function in model of laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

One of my eloquent model in laravel have a function that returns rate for each data, Now I want select ones that have this rate value in a specific range,

```
class Article extends Model
{
     public function rate() {
         return c*this->value->count();
     }
}

public function trends()
{
    $articles = Article::where('?', ?); 
    return response()->json($articles, 200);
}
```

You know guys, I want to use 'where' insist a loop because there are multiple where in Article model.